# How to inspect a value and re-render when the value is changed in ReactJS hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have two value to inspect and display to my page: `connected`(boolean) and `publicKey`(PublicKey).
If the value of any one is changed, re-render the component and displayed the changed value on the page.

Currently my code is as below, it won't show the changes even the value was updated.
What should I do?

```
import { useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function TestComponent() {
    const { connected, publicKey } = useWallet();

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Is Connect?: {connected}</h2>
            <h2>Public Key: {publicKey?.toString}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And the source code of `useWallet()` is about:

```
export interface WalletContextState extends WalletAdapterProps {
    wallets: Wallet[];
    autoConnect: boolean;
    wallet: Wallet | null;
}

export interface WalletAdapterProps {
    publicKey: PublicKey | null;
    connected: boolean;
}

export const WalletContext = createContext<WalletContextState>({} as WalletContextState);

export function useWallet(): WalletContextState {
    return useContext(WalletContext);
}
```

Comment: The component will only update if a state or prop variable changes. You can have state variables for `connected` and `publicKey` and with respective setter methods `setConnected` nd `setPublicKey`. Or just call the useWallet hook on the parent of TestComponent and pass  `connected` and `publicKey` as props so when they update it will trigger a render

Comment: @Amruta Sorry I'm still new to React, could you give me some code examples? Thank you.

Comment: we can help you with sample if you can explain bit more about useWallet(), since i fell like it's a function call that is invoked once and return value is assigned to variables after that where are the values getting changed that you like to keep updated with?

Comment: @Vishwa sure, I add the source code of useWallet() in my post, hope it helps.

Comment: Can you try importing 'WalletContext' also in line 1 along with useWallet, may be it will work or below answer might work too

Comment: Hi @Vishwa, I tried both of it but neither of it worked.  In console I could see the value is changed but in the <div> those value remained unchanged :(

Comment: The key thing here is that if `WalletContext` isn't tracking changes in real-time then there's not much your component can do about it. If it is tracking changes in real-time then the context change will already be causing a re-render. Perhaps there's some other part of their API for making sure changes to the system trigger updates on the client.